# Using browser(s) with 2 internet connection simultaneously, but separately

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, network-shares, routing, modem

I'm wondering how to setup two browsers to use each own internet connection.

I have WLAN and standard bluetooth modem connections each providing internet access independently. But whenever I connect via bluetooth modem, it takes over browser network connectivity. I wonder if I can setup one browser (e.g., Firefox) to use WLAN and other browser (e.g., Chrome, or even better different Firefox profile) to use bluetooth connection.

PS.
As an alternative, I wonder if I can do the same with 2 WLANS - one from built-in card and and the other from USB WLAN card.

Comment: I assume you have the hardware that allows you to do this.  One simply way would be to use two differnt proxy configurations.

Comment: No, I'm not using any additional hardware. Just standard Windows network functionality with WLAN and Bluetooth.

Answer (score 2):

There is a program called ForceBindIP which allows you to specify an interface for the desired application. You can create shortcuts on your desktop with the ForceBindIP script that will connect one browser to the bluetooth connection and the other browser to the wireless connection. To take this a step further, you can use Metrics (see http://helpdeskgeek.com/networking/force-windows-7-to-use-wired-connection-over-wireless/) so that your wireless has priority over bluetooth (or vice versa) for any other application.

ForceBindIP is a freeware Windows application that will inject itself into another application and alter how certain Windows Sockets calls are made, allowing you to force the other application to use a specific network interface / IP address. This is useful if you are in an environment with multiple interfaces and your application has no such option for binding to a specific interface.

http://old.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but unfortunately in didn't work out. Software seems to be outdated (latest update in 2009), at least for Windows 7 x64.
I've tried different ways - installed and standalone ForceBindIP, binding to IP and GUID, tried 3 browsers (x32 and x64). Nothing worked :(

Comment: And its a good point with Metrics! To make WLAN priority higher than Bluetooth modem. But it didn't work for me either. I assume bluetooth connection falls under the naming "Remote Access connections", but it was already the last one in my list - http://goo.gl/RxueoY.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the commandline-tool [ForcecebindIP](http://old.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/).

The tool isn't working with 64bit applications.

It can bind any application to a specific interface.

So if you want to bind Firefox to wifi for example:

1. Find the local IP of the wifi/networks you are connected to.
2. Now you have to add this ip to the application:

   ```
   ForceBindIP 1.2.3.4 c:\full\path\to\app.exe
   ```
3. Now you can add the IP of the bluetooth-connection to the other application:

   ```
   ForceBindIP 4.3.2.1 c:\full\path\to\app.exe
   ```

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it doesn't work on my Windows 7 x64 at all. I've tested with few browsers - Firefox, Opera, Chromium (all x32). I've tried IP and GUID binding as well. I guess this software is outdated for later Windows versions.